# Generic List Insert method

Tags: powershell

While I have no problem when adding arrays to a generic list, I am facing issues when trying to insert them :

```
$myList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
[string[]]$myArr1 = "one", "two", "three"
[string[]]$myArr2 = "four", "five", "six"
$myList.AddRange($myArr2)
$myList.Insert(0, $myArr1)
$myList
```

is returning

```
one two three
four
five
six
```

while

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

is awaited.
I have tried `$myList.Insert(0, {$myArr1}.Invoke())` without any success.

Facing another  issue :

```
$mypart = [System.Collections.Generic.List[CimInstance]]::new()
[CimInstance[]]$disk0 = Get-Partition -DiskNumber 0
[CimInstance[]]$disk1 = Get-Partition -DiskNumber 1
$mypart.AddRange($disk1)
$mypart.Insert(0, $disk0)
$mypart
```

Here, `Insert` method throw an error "overload with 2 arguments not found".

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like [`.AddRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1.AddRange) (rather than just `.Add()`) is required to append the elements of a *collection* (individually) in a single operation, you need to use [`.InsertRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1.InsertRange) (rather than just `.Insert()`) to do the same for an *insert* operation.

The reason that the attempting `.Insert()` with a `[string]` array did not fail is that PowerShell quietly converted the string array to a single string, by space-concatenating the elements (as `"$('one', 'two')"` would). For a `[CimInstance]` array, no such conversion can be performed, which is why an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never notice that one, I should be blind ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @CFou; my pleasure; thanks for accepting.